# SVN lock is not releasing

Tags: linux, svn, svnlook

I'm using SVN in Ubuntu. When I was trying to change IP on of repository, my computer accidentally shut down. Now I'm unable to change IP with command `svn switch --relocate <old repository> <new repository>`. When I'm trying to do it, I'm always getting error that says:

```
svn: Working copy '.' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
```

I've tried suggested command `svn cleanup`, but nothing happens for a long time. 
Is the unique way to solve this problem is to clone repository again?

Comment: If "clone" means "checkout" then you are probably right. The working copy format has never been particularly robust, not even WC-NG. But let's wait and see if someone corrects me.

Comment: What version of svn are you using?  I'm guessing 1.6 since you mention Ubuntu and that's the newest they include.  It'd be interesting to me if you can run `strace svn cleanup` and see what it's hanging on.  But in general probably the easiest way to resolve your problem is a fresh `svn checkout`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @BenReser, yes, I'm using svn 1.6 and when I'm executing `strace svn cleanup` nothing is appearing. But when I'm executing it in not locked copy of repository it is printing a lot of things, like mkdir,close,lstat,..

Comment: Really not much to go on there.  If it's not a huge issue I'd create a new checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`svn unlock --force TARGET`

or

`svnadmin rmlocks TARGET`

Where target may be the repo url or the working copy.